# How To Use LibCurl's Https GET When Accessing Webserver

Tags: php, c++, .htaccess, curl, libcurl

Ok, so to start out, I'm a complete rookie when it comes to libcurl, or any sort of client/server communication.  I have this c++ service that runs wmi logs every night at 1:00, which I'm going to be sending to the serverside to insert them into a database.  We currently have the serverside set up with a .htaccess file that converts the last portion of the url into the HTTPS get value.   So for example, when I go to https://url.org/srv/version/machineuuidhere, if it doesn't already exist, it inserts 'machineuuidhere' into our clients table. The functionality of this works great when using the browser.  However, I would like to do this in a funcion in my cpp service.

I've played around with libcurl and looked at its api and whatnot.  I ended up finding [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html) tutorial, and just scraped the code, adding it into mine, with the only exception being manipulating the url to be `"https://url.org/srv/version/" + machineuuid;`.  I figured this works, but it doesn't for an unknown reason.  The error it throws when running it is: `curl_easy_perform() failed: Couldn't resolve host name`.  Obviously this is just curl's error reporting in the tutorial code itself, so the program continues to run fine after that.  Like I mentioned before, I'm positive the url is good and it works in the browser, so I don't know why it can't resolve the host name.

If anyone has some sort of fix, work around, or completely different solution, it would be greatly appreciated!

(Not sure if you guys need the php code or not, but I haven't included it for the purpose of keeping the post short.  Let me know and I will, and thanks in advance!)

Comment: can you resolve the hostname with nslookup?

Comment: But this is PHP?  Maybe we do need to see some PHP code....

Comment: It was a dupe!  I was passing in a string!  Used url.c_str() to remedy the issue!  Is it standard to just close the question or delete it since its a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing that out though!